# Subtraction of values of given array satisfying certain condition:

Tags: matlab

```
a = [0.04 0.07 0.09 0.13 0.14 0.17 0.21 0.24
0.14 0.06 0.08 0.15 0.11 0.13 0.10 0.11
0.13 0.13 0.11 0.15 0.10 0.07 0.14 0.11
0.12 0.04 0.18 0.13 0.19 0.16 0.14 0.11
0.18 0.06 0.22 0.15 0.14 0.06 0.08 0.09
0.15 0.04 0.08 0.06 0.13 0.05 0.10 0.09]

C = cov(a)
alpha = 0.12
beta = (.20-.12)

for i = 1 : 6
    for j = 1 : 8
        f(i,j) = alpha + beta*rand(1)
    end     
    % f(i,1)=f(i,1)/sum;f(i,2)=f(i,2)/sum;f(i,3)=f(i,3)/sum;
end
total = sum(f,2)
while total(i,1) > .999 & total (i,1) <.977
    for i = 1:6
        for i = 1:8
            f(i,j) = f(i,j) - .0001
        end
    end
end
```

I've been trying to subtract .0001 from every element of array `f` such that the value of every resulting element of array elements should be between 0.12 and 0.20 and rowwise the sum (variable `total` in the code) of the array `f`  should be nearly equal to 1. By nearly I mean value of the sum (variable `total` in the code) should be less than (`<`) 0.999 and  greater than (`>`) .977

Comment: The rules you state allow a fairly arbitrary order of subtraction. I could subtract 0.0001 from the first value as long as it is greater than 0.12 and the sum is to large. Or, I could subtract the value from each element where it is possible once, then start again at the beginning. It might help us if you could state where you want to go.

Comment: Another thing: It is not guaranteed that there will even be a solution. Imagine your random array has one row with all values smaller than 0.122 - then there would be no way to fulfill your conditions just by subtracting. By the way: What is the variable C in your code is for?

Comment: So you want to clamp your array and also normalize each row to 1? Which one takes precedence if the two conditions conflict? Can you provide a pseudocode algorithm and/or test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lb = 0.12; 
ub = 0.20;
sensitivity = 0.02;
inc = 0.001;


f = lb + (ub-lb).*rand([6,8]); % See Note Below
total = sum(f,2);
f = f./repmat(total + sensitivity,[1,8]);

while(any(any(g<lb)) || any(any(g>ub)) || any(total>0.99) || any(total<0.97))

    f(f<lb) = lb + inc;
    f(f>ub) = ub - inc;

    total = sum(g,2);
    f = f./repmat(total + sensitivity,[1,8]);
    inc = inc + 0.001;
end
```

Note: In general, it is bad to do nested for-loops in matlab when you can do matrix manipulation. So this one line replaces the nested for loops you have to create f or to decrement from it.

This code should give you a matrix f that (1) has values between 0.12 (lb) and 0.20 (ub) and has row-sum totals that is around 0.98.